# With support library 27.1.1, when i start an activity my app freezes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-support-library, freeze, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to update the compileSDKVersion to 27, so I also changed the support library to 27.1.1.

Now my app starts as always but when I try to start a new activity the app freezes. 
It also freezes when resuming after the background mode.

Some code:

**HomeActivity**

This is the first activity that works, freeze only if resumed after background

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener,
    FirebaseUpdaterController.Listener{
private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {   // first opened
        savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getString(COUPLE_UID) != null) {
        Utility.saveStringPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.PARTNER_UID, savedInstanceState.getString(PARTNER_UID));
        Utility.saveStringPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.PARTNER_USERNAME, savedInstanceState.getString(PARTNER_USERNAME));
        Utility.saveStringPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.PARTNER_IMAGE_URI, savedInstanceState.getString(PARTNER_IMAGE_URI));
        Utility.saveStringPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.COUPLE_UID, savedInstanceState.getString(COUPLE_UID));
        super.updateRepositories();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

    Utility.askStoragePermission(this);
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(MULTI_COUPLE_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
        BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new ChangeCoupleBottomSheetDialogFragment();
        //show it
        bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
    }

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar);
    mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    mToolbar.getLayoutParams().height = UtilisGraphic.getStatusBarHeight(this) + (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.app_bar_height);
    mToolbar.setPadding(0, UtilisGraphic.getStatusBarHeight(this), 0, 0);
    mToolbar.requestLayout();
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    mFirebaseSuggestionsController = new FirebaseSuggestionsController(
            mUserUid,
            Utility.getStringPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.USERNAME),
            Utility.getStringPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.DEBUG)
    );

    mFirebaseUpdaterController = new FirebaseUpdaterController(
            mUserUid,
            Utility.getStringPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.DEBUG)
    );

    mFirebaseUpdaterController.setListener(this);

    mDialog =
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .iconRes(R.drawable.suggestions_icon)
                    .limitIconToDefaultSize()
                    .title(R.string.questioner_dialog_title)
                    .customView(R.layout.custom_dialog_suggestions, true)
                    .positiveText(R.string.affermative_suggestions_dialog)
                    .negativeText(R.string.negative_suggestions_dialog)
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(MaterialDialog dialog, DialogAction which) {
                            suggestionText = suggestionInput.getText().toString();

                            sendSuggestions(selectedRadio, suggestionText);

                            Utility.saveBooleanPreference(getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefKeys.SUGGESTION_SENT, true);

                            mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_suggestions).setVisible(false);
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

    positiveActionSuggestion = mDialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE);

    suggestionInput = (EditText) mDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.suggestion_input_edittex);
    suggestionInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    suggestionInput.addTextChangedListener(
            new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    positiveActionSuggestion.setEnabled(s.toString().trim().length() > 5);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            });

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) mDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
    radioGroup.check(R.id.radio_0);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.radio_0:
                    selectedRadio = 0;
                    suggestionInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    suggestionInput.clearFocus();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_1:
                    selectedRadio = 1;
                    suggestionInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    suggestionInput.clearFocus();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_2:
                    selectedRadio = 2;
                    suggestionInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    suggestionInput.clearFocus();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_other:
                    selectedRadio = 3;
                    suggestionInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    suggestionInput.requestFocus();
                    if(suggestionInput.getText().length() < 6) {
                        positiveActionSuggestion.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    mView = (HomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.home_fragment_container);


    if (mView == null) {
        mView = HomeFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getExtras());
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.home_fragment_container, mView);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getStringExtra(URI) != null){
        mUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra(URI));
        ChatRepository.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setUriImportWa(mUri);
        intent.removeExtra(URI);
        //changePageTo(DashboardPagerAdapter.HOME_TAB);
    }
}}
```

**BaseActivity**

All activities extend this base class

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    ForceUpdateChecker.OnUpdateNeededListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

    // set in-app defaults
    Map<String, Object> remoteConfigDefaults = new HashMap();
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED, false);
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_CURRENT_VERSION, "1.0.0");
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_URL,
            "https://google.com");

    firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaults);
    firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(MINUTE_TO_FETCH) // fetch every minutes
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(BASE_TAG, "remote config is fetched.");
                        firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                    }
                }
            });

    // Getting utils data for all activity
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if(sp.getBoolean(SharedPrefKeys.USER_RELATIONSHIP_STATUS_CHANGED, false)){
        checkUserRelationshipStatus();
    }

    mUserUid = sp.getString(SharedPrefKeys.USER_UID, SharedPrefKeys.DEFAULT_VALUE);
    mCoupleUid = sp.getString(SharedPrefKeys.COUPLE_UID, mUserUid);

    if(MainActivity.apiServiceAmazon == null){

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        Retrofit retrofitAmazon = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL_AMAZON_EB)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        MainActivity.apiServiceAmazon = retrofitAmazon.create(ServerApiAmazonInterface.class);

        Retrofit retrofitCloud = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL_CLOUD_FUNCTION)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        MainActivity.apiServiceCloud = retrofitCloud.create(ServerApiCloudFunctionInterface.class);
    }
    if (MainActivity.db == null) {
        MainActivity.db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                SweetieDatabase.class, "DB").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
    }


    /* Setup the Google API object to allow Google logins */
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_ID))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    /* Setup the Google API object to allow Google+ logins */
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .enableAutoManage(this, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}
```

**HomeFragment**

Fragment where i start other activities that freeze the app.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements LifecycleOwner, SweetboxCardAdapter.SweetboxCardAdapterListener, SweetBoxReadScanner.onCounter, ChooseCoupleAdapter.ChooseCoupleAdapterListener {


public static HomeFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    HomeFragment newHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    newHomeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return newHomeFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
    mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
    mAnimShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_left);
    mAnimShowFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
    mAnimscaleIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.scale_up);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout_scrollable, container, false);

    mCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.import_progress_dialog_view,null);
    mCompleteImportCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.import_complete_dialog_view, null);
    mCompleteImportCustomView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCompleteImportDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mTitleTextView = (EmojiconTextView) root.findViewById(R.id.action_item_title);
    mDiaryDescription = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.sweetbox_card_description_view);
    mDescriptionTextView = (EmojiconTextView) root.findViewById(R.id.action_item_subtitle);
    mDateTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.action_item_date);
    mAppBarImageView = (CircleImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_image_view);
    mAppBarImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mNoAppBarImageTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_no_image_text);
    mNoAppBarImageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mHeartOff = root.findViewById(R.id.sweetbox_card_heart_off);
    mFullHeart = root.findViewById(R.id.sweetbox_card_full_heart);

    mAppBarExtension = root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mAppBarExtension.getLayoutParams().height =(int) UtilisGraphic.dpToPx(50, getContext()) + UtilisGraphic.getStatusBarHeight(getContext());
    mAppBarExtension.requestLayout();

    mAvatarImageView = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_action_list_item);
    mNoImageTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.action_no_image_text);

    mTypeIcon = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.action_item_type);
    mNotificCounter = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.action_item_notification_counter);

    avatarClickZone = (View) root.findViewById(R.id.avatar_click_zone);

    actionClickZone = (View) root.findViewById(R.id.action_click_zone);

    mChangeCoupleFab = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.change_couple_fab);
    mChangeCoupleFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = ChangeCoupleBottomSheetDialogFragment.getInstance(getActivity());
            //show it
            bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
        }
    });


    mDiaryCard = (CardView) root.findViewById(R.id.diary_card_view);
    mDiaryCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mChatCard = (CardView) root.findViewById(R.id.chat_card_view);
    mChatCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mCardStackView = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) root.findViewById(R.id.home_sweetbox_recycler_view);
    mArrayList = new ArrayList<MessageVM>();
    mSweetboxAdapter = new SweetboxCardAdapter(getContext());
    mCardStackView.setAdapter(mSweetboxAdapter);
    mSweetboxAdapter.setListener(this);

    mCardStackView.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
            mHeartOff.startAnimation(mAnimscaleIn);
            MessageVM messageVM = (MessageVM) dataObject;
            ChatRepository.getInstance(getContext()).discardMessage(messageVM, MessageVM.TEXT_MSG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
            mFullHeart.startAnimation(mAnimscaleIn);
            MessageVM messageVM = (MessageVM) dataObject;
            messageVM.setBookmarked(true);
            ChatRepository.getInstance(getContext()).bookmarkMessage(messageVM, MessageVM.TEXT_MSG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
            // Ask for more data here
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(float v) {

        }
    });

    mHomeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

    createObservers();
    setupAppBar();
    setupChatCard();
    setupDiaryCard();
    return root;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(ChatRepository.getInstance(getContext()).isImportWa()){
        mUri = ChatRepository.getInstance(getContext()).getUriImportWa();
        mFileName = "cache_file.txt";
        try {
            mTextFileStream = new DataInputStream(getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri));
            File file = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), mFileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // or other buffer size
                int read;

                while ((read = mTextFileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                output.flush();
            } finally {
                output.close();
                mTextFileStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(mTextFileStream != null) {
            mUri = null;
            ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).clearUri();
            ChatRepository.getInstance(getContext()).clearUriImportWa();
            mDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(getContext())
                    .title(R.string.where_import)
                    // second parameter is an optional layout manager. Must be a LinearLayoutManager or GridLayoutManager.
                    .adapter(new ChooseCoupleAdapter(getContext(),this), new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3))
                    .build();
            mDialog.show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't open the uri");
        }

    }
}
private void setupChatCard() {
        final String coupleUid = Utility.getStringPreference(getContext(), SharedPrefKeys.COUPLE_UID);
        String userUid = Utility.getStringPreference(getContext(), SharedPrefKeys.USER_UID);
        mTitleText = getString(R.string.personal_messages);
        if(!userUid.equals(coupleUid)){
            mTitleText = Utility.getStringPreference(getContext(),SharedPrefKeys.PARTNER_USERNAME);
        }
        mTitleTextView.setText(mTitleText);
        mHomeViewModel.getMainChatDate(getContext(), Utility.getStringPreference(getContext(), SharedPrefKeys.COUPLE_UID)).observe(this, mChatDateObserver);
        mHomeViewModel.getMainChatDescription(getContext(), Utility.getStringPreference(getContext(), SharedPrefKeys.COUPLE_UID)).observe(this, mChatDescriptionObserver);
        mHomeViewModel.getMainChatImage(getContext(), Utility.getStringPreference(getContext(), SharedPrefKeys.COUPLE_UID)).observe(this, mChatImageObserver);
        mHomeViewModel.getMainChatNotificCounter(getContext(), Utility.getStringPreference(getContext(), SharedPrefKeys.COUPLE_UID)).observe(this, mChatNotificCounterObserver);
        avatarClickZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //if in couples
                if(coupleUid != null && !coupleUid.equals(Utility.getStringPreference( getContext(),SharedPrefKeys.USER_UID))){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), CoupleDetailsActivity.class));
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChatActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.ACTION_DATABASE_KEY, coupleUid);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        actionClickZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChatActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.ACTION_DATABASE_KEY, coupleUid);
                animateChatIntent(mChatCard, intent);
            }
        });
        mChatCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mChatCard.startAnimation(mAnimShow);
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- activity -->

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".tutorial.InitTutorialActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ChatTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ChatTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".registration.RegistrationActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ChatTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".pairing.PairingActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".home.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".home.HomeActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".chatMVVM.ChatActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".home.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ChatTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".home.HomeActivity"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="open_chat_intent_filter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity android:name=".couple.CoupleActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".home.HomeActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".home.HomeActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".couple.CoupleDetailsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>


    <activity android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".home.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".home.HomeActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".chatMVVM.ChatInfoActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".chatMVVM.ChatActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".chatMVVM.ChatActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".home.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/HomeTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".diaryMVVM.DiaryActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
```

Comment: try to add some codes to your question

Comment: There can be millions of reasons  app can freeze , we can't help unless you show us what you did

Comment: I posted some code. I hope is enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @luhahaha actually, it is too much code. Try to come up with a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: @Hanry the problem is that I don't know what is the problem! :) 
With sdk 26 and support 26.1.0 everything go well, with 27 it freezes.
I realized that the freeze happens when i start a new activity or i resume the HomeActivity after a background. But I can't find where is the exact point where the problem start, so i tried to put the homeactivity, the fragment and the manifest